# Glide.js script only working inside the console

Tags: jquery, wordpress, var, unexpected-token, glidejs

I am using Glide.js to display sliders on my website. To display one slide, I am using the following code:

```
document.querySelector(".resources-carousel") &&
((resourcesCarousel = new Glide(".resources-carousel", { 
  type: "slider", 
  perView: 4, 
  gap: 20 
})),
resourcesCarousel.mount());
```

On another page, I would like to display multiple sliders using this code:

```
var resourceSliders = document.querySelectorAll('.resources-carousel');
for (var i = 0; i < resourceSliders.length; i++) { 
    var glide = new Glide(resourceSliders[i],{
        type:"slider",
        perView:4,
        gap:20,
    });
    glide.mount();
}
```

The code works fine and initialises both sliders when pasted in to the console, however when I add this code to my scripts.js file in Wordpress I get the following error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'**

How can I fix this?

Comment: where are you seeing this error?

Comment: In the console when I publish the changes. It also breaks all other scripts inside script.js

Comment: are you compiling your scripts at all?

Comment: Yes it is all compiled inside one file